# Where to get the link-only text from?

Tags: discussion, support, link-only-answers

Came across [this answer (*deleted so >10K*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646636/how-to-check-variable-type-using-type-function-in-sikuli/20049000#20049000) and wanted to leave a comment saying

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

instead of voting for deletion or any other action.

It would have been really handy if I could somehow auto-generate this message instead of having to go to a review queue and wait til a post pop-up in so I can copy-paste the reason (*which I can't really do any longer as selection on the popup box is disabled*)

I realize I can construct my own message but for the consistency I prefer using the community's common message.

I've flagged for deletion and the answer has been removed but still. There are [many other occasions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045151/how-to-setup-naked-domain) where I'd rather just leave a message like the above.

Have I missed it somewhere or should I consider putting a feature-request together?

Comment: I use a clipboard tool (Ditto) to select and paste snippets of mine rather fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a userscript called [Pro-Forma comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se), which inserts an "auto" link next to all comment boxes. Upon pressing it, you can choose from a list of customisable comment templates to insert.

For more info (and an install link), see the Stack Apps page; [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

Comment: excellent - exactly what I needed. Just installed the script and it works just fine!